# Comparing strings case-insensitively

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to compare `Hello World` to `hello world`. The result should be true, as if they were equal. I'm doing:

```
while read line; do

    newLine="$newLine$line"
done < $1

newp="Hello World"
if (( ${newp,,}==${newLine,,} )); then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"

fi
```

when I pass a text file consisting of:

```
#filename: file.txt

hello world
```

The output seems to be:

```
./testScript.txt: line 20: 0à»: hello world==hello world : syntax error in expression (error token is "world==hello world ")
+ echo false
```

What am I doing wrong here? Also, a bit unrelated, is there any way to pass the line that is in `file.txt` to a string(newLine) without doing that `while` I have done?

Comment: `(( a == b ))` is for math and numbers. `[[ "$a" = "$b" ]]` is for strings. The spaces are not optional.

Comment: Even if you get an answer to your specific question, the surrounding loop means that any test will say that `x\y` matches `xy` and can have other false [mis]matches. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: You may use `grep -v` with one style of `hello world` to test the other style.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add commas and change the double parentheses to single brackets. The if statement should be something like:

```
if [ "${newp,,}" = "${newLine,,}" ]; then
```

And in relation to that while loop... It depends on what you want to do. If, like in this case, you want to get the entire file and save it as a single string, you could simply do:

```
line=$(cat $1)
```

I would suggest you only use that loop you wrote if you are trying to parse the file line by line, i.e. adding if statements, using different variables and so on. But for a simple case like this one, `cat` will do just fine.

Comment: The surrounding loop means that this test will say that `x\y` matches `xy` and can have other false matches. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0):

There is a [shell option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin), `nocasematch`, that enables case insensitive pattern matching for use with `[[` and `case`.

Comparing strings that differ by casing only:

```
$ var1=lowercase
$ var2=LOWERCASE
$ [[ $var1 == $var2 ]] && echo "Matches!" || echo "Doesn't match!"
Doesn't match!
```

Now enabling the shell option and trying again:

```
$ shopt -s nocasematch
$ [[ $var1 == $var2 ]] && echo "Matches!" || echo "Doesn't match!"
Matches!
```

Just make sure to turn it off again with `shopt -u nocasematch` if you don't want to do *all* comparisons case insensitive.